# Opacity over Flash doesn't works

Tags: flash, visibility, opacity

I'm trying to make an animation over a YouTube video. The problem is that when flash is not activated, all works fine, but when I activate flash, the div goes below the video a you can't see it. I tried to use z-index, but it doesnt works. Here are some videos to ilustrate:

This is how the animations should look: https://mega.co.nz/#!iVNExIxL!X_kxDWHtIPChRNz-Mef_KQ499QEluuc0rR-FHTYjUN0

And this happens when activating flash: https://mega.co.nz/#!fZk03J6D!KbY6CT7KTWnOg4a42K-UQx7vGGNxZ1zinaZnI8IpkmE

Here is the code used:

```
#div {
left:698px;
top:65px;
width:320px;
height:390px;
visibility:visible;
animation:open 6s reverse ease-in;
}
@keyframes open {
0% {left:698px;opacity:0;visibility:collapse;}
50% {left:338px;opacity:1;visibility:visible;}
100% {left:698px;opacity:0;visibility:collapse;}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `opaque` for the `wmode` parameter when you embed the Flash object on your page.  The other value for `wmode` that might be relevant is `transparent`.  You can read about them [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html). Both of these allow you to layer things on top of or behind the Flash app.

Note, that using these `wmode` values makes Flash have to work harder. It also can expose issues in some browsers, and it will break accessibility in the Flash app if that is a concern. Don't mean to alarm you, the bugs are often corner cases and you probably won't notice any performance issues unless you're doing rocket science.